# how to take backup of RPD and Catalog of OBIEE12c?

Tags: oracle, aix, obiee

I would like to take backup of RPD (i.e., OBIEE12c metadata) and Catalog (i.e., save BI analytical reports, dashboard saved in both my folders and shared folders) in order to restore in the test server for the research purpose.

OBIEE12c Version: 12.2.1.4

Operating System: AIX 7.1

Answer (score 0):

You may take backup of RPD and Catalog using exportarchive utility

Syntax:

```
[DOMAIN_HOME]/bitools/bin/exportarchive.sh ssi <Bar file name>.bar encryptionpassword=<password>
```

Example:

```
[DOMAIN_HOME]/bitools/bin/exporarchive.sh ssi /backupdir/obitest.bar encryptionpassword='Test123'
```