# Why there are some hidden files in OBIEE12c catlog

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, obiee

i have seen in catlog there are some random files and they are in hidden mode.the file names are

like

eecf62800bfd100085670ae4a5190000

are they are importnt while archiving .please let me know

i am new to obi .so please consider breif explanaton

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/69171637/685806

Comment: What does this have to do with java?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In the OBIEE Catalog under scorecards there are some hiddenfiles exist are they really need. can we delete?